# Find maximum likelihood estimators of PDF

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I am quite stumped by the following problem. The usual log-likelihood route with differentiation doesn't work. The problem is as follows:

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables from a distribution with
>   p.d.f.:
>
> $$f(x; \theta_1, \theta_2) = \frac{1}{\theta_2} \text{exp}(-\frac{(x -
>  \theta_1)}{\theta_2}) \: \text{for } x \geq \theta_1$$
>
> with parameters $\theta_1 \in R$ and $\theta_2 > 0$.
>
> Find maximum likelihood estimators of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$

Any hints or insights?

What I tried:

[image]

Comment: If you set the partial derivatives to 0 can't solve the 2 equations in 2 unknowns. If the solution is not unique verify which one is a global maximum. If the solution is unique toy should still be able to verify that it is a maximum.

Comment: In the middle of your notebook paper you have $\log{L}=-\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n x(i)}{\theta _2}+\frac{\theta _1 n}{\theta _2}-n \log \left(\theta _2\right)$.  Note that this function can increases with increasing $\theta_1$ and the largest value $\theta_1$ can possibly take is the minimum $x_i$.  That should tell you what the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta_1$ is.

Comment: There seems to be an error in your last calculation. Shouldn't the last term be $-n\theta_1/\theta_2^2$

Comment: You should review your basic material on finding global and local maxima. You should have been taught that setting derivatives to 0 won't always find the maximum (e.g. try it on "find the maximum of $f(x)=1/x$ in the interval $1\leq x\leq 2$"). If you try to set the derivative to $0$ you get nowhere. You've forgotten some important facts! As a first step, consider $\theta_2=1$ and *try drawing a picture* of the log-likelihood as a function of $\theta_1$ (keeping in mind the relationship between $\theta_1$ and any observation).

Answer (score 1):

To close this one:

This is the pdf of a shifted Exponential random variable, $Y \sim \text{Exp}(\theta_2)$ (scale parameter), and $X = Y + \theta_1$.

From the condition $X\geq \theta_1$, the MLE is immediately obtained as

$$\hat \theta_{MLE} = X_{(1)}$$

i.e. the minimum order statistic and so the actual estimate will be the minimum value available in the sample.  This can be verified by directly inspecting the log-likelihood as suggested in a comment.

Then apply "concentrated ML" estimation, i.e. plug the minimum $x$-value in place of $\theta_1$ and optimize as usual with respect to $\theta_2$ only.